# Hide/show sections in UICollectionView from code (swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS development and developing my first app for iOS 8, XCode 6.3, Swift 1.2. I have a small problem with hiding and showing sections in the UICollectionView.

So I have a main ViewController.swift, SettingsViewController.swift. My task is to hide/show sections, one switch control for every section in the SettingViewController.

I have a following model:
Member.swift:

```
class Member {
var Name: String
var Image: String

init (Name: String, Image: String){
    self.Name = Name
    self.Image = Image  
}   
}
```

Group.swift:

```
class Group {    
var Name: String
var Members: [Member]

init (Name: String, Members: [Member]){
    self.Name = Name
    self.Members = Members     
}   
}
```

In the ViewController.swift I create objects for data source of the UICollectionView

```
class ViewController:
...
var Groups: [Group] = []

var Group1 = Group(Name: "Group 1", Members: [])
var Group2 = Group(Name: "Group 2", Members: [])
var Group3 = Group(Name: "Group 3", Members: [])

override func viewDidLoad() {
...
    CreateMembers()
    LoadGroups()

}

func CreateMembers() -> Void {

    var member1 = Member(Name: "Member 1 in Group 1", Image: "face1")
    var member2 = Member(Name: "Member 2 in Group 2", Image: "face2")
    var member3 = Member(Name: "Member 3 in Group 3", Image: "face3")

    Group1.Members.append(member1)
    Group2.Members.append(member2)
    Group3.Members.append(member3)

}
```

and data source methods are implemented to show members in each Group, and one Group is a section, name of the Group is specified in the header view of the section. I load groups to the Groups array depending on user settings at start:

```
func LoadGroups() -> Void {

    Groups = []

    if ShowGroup1 {
        Groups.append(Group1)
    }
    if ShowGroup2 {
        Groups.append(Group2)
    }
    if ShowGroup3 {
        Groups.append(Group3)
    }     
}
```

I have a segue method to get value from SettingsViewController and reload groups which is called when I tap Save button in the SettingsViewController, method is defined in the ViewController:

```
@IBAction func saveSettings(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let settingsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? SettingsViewController {
        ShowGroup2 = settingsViewController.ShowGroup2
        LoadGroups()            
    }
}
```

In the method LoadGroup() I decided to clear Groups array to load it again depending on changed settings after tapping on switch control.

Problem: when I tap on switch control to make ShowGroup2 false, I tap Save button, main View is appeared, now I scroll collection and fatal error is appeared:"fatal error: Array index out of range".

In the official documentation: "Besides embedding it in your user interface, you use the methods of UICollectionView object to ensure that the visual presentation of items matches the order in your data source object." I added outlet for UICollectionView and trying to delete section using    func deleteSections(_ sections: NSIndexSet)    , but I do not see this method for outlet. Please help with a right way to refresh collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an outlet for your `UICollectionView` so that you can use it in code. Then try adding a call to reload the `UICollectionView` when your data is updated at the end of `LoadGroups()`

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: thanks :D as I described previously I already added outlet for collection view, but outlet has wrong type of UIView instead of UICollectionView. But in which case I need to call deleteSections() method? How can I delete and add sections with animation?